# Creating new variable based on a specific result in any of a list of variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

So I want to create a new conditional variable like the one below. Basically, I want a variable that signifies any positive result in a list of other variables. I've been trying to use case_when but having no luck.

| variable 1 | variable 2 | varaible 3 | New variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: `+(rowSums(DF) > 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pmap_dbl` to apply an if_else statement that checks whether any values of `var1`, `var2` or `var3` are positive. This solution works no matter what the numeric values of the above variables are.

```
library(tidyverse)

# reproduce your data
mydata <- tibble(
  var1 = c(1,0,0,0),
  var2 = c(0,0,1,0),
  var3 = c(0,1,1,0)
)

mydata %>%
  mutate(
     newvar = pmap_dbl(list(var1, var2, var3), ~ if_else(any(c(..1, ..2, ..3) > 0), 1, 0))
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood what you were looking for correctly. I created `new_var` variable based on the presence of any positive value in a row:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_var = +any(c_across(everything()) > 0, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  variable1 variable2 variable3 new_var
      <int>     <int>     <int>   <int>
1         1         0         0       1
2         0         0         1       1
3         0         1         1       1
4         0         0         0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

using `cur_data()` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(new_v = +(rowSums(cur_data()) > 0))

#>   variable1 variable2 variable3 new_v
#> 1         1         0         0     1
#> 2         0         0         1     1
#> 3         0         1         1     1
#> 4         0         0         0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can find the max value in each row.

```
df$new_variable <- do.call(pmax, df)
df

#  variable1 variable2 variable3 new_variable
#1         1         0         0            1
#2         0         0         1            1
#3         0         1         1            1
#4         0         0         0            0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(variable1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variable2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), variable3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), new_variable = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce` with `|` in `base R` so that any value not equal to 0 will be TRUE for and 0 FALSE which does the elementwise comparison for each row and returns TRUE if there is at least one non-zero, then we coerce the logical to binary with `+` (TRUE -> 1, FALSE -> 0)

```
df$new_variable <- +(Reduce(`|`, df))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(variable1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variable2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), variable3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```